# Website as background - alternative to Active Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, desktop-customization

I need to **constantly display website** on computers I am managing (Windows 7, Windows 10).

The simplest solution would be to set this website as background (wallpaper) but this feature is no longer supported by MS.

Maybe there's some alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know user can make a web page an active background on Windows XP, but on Windows 10, maybe you need to a third-party software. Refer to this link below.

How To Set A Webpage As Desktop Background In Windows 10

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-set-a-webpage-as-desktop-background-in-windows-10/

Comment: It doesn’t replace the actual Windows desktop, it covers it fully, i. e. no way to access the actual desktop (icons etc.). I am aware of third party applications but I am looking for solutions to constantly displaying website somehow, it doesn't have to be active desktop, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try [Lively Wallpaper](https://github.com/rocksdanister/lively)!
it was all I needed!

> Free and open-source application for setting GIFs, Videos, and Webpages as your desktop wallpaper and screensaver!
> This is an open-source project and community participation is welcome.
> To participate please visit https://github.com/rocksdanister/lively

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers, instead quote the most important parts from the linked site.